# Extraer palabras de un patron en c#

Tags: c#, string

Me preguntaba como podría extraer las palabras que hay, teniendo un patrón.

Por ejemplo, dado el siguiente string, extraer la palabra de dentro:

```
Palabra 1: "Raqueta" end:
Palabra 2: "Motocicleta" end:
```

Es solo un mero ejemplo, el caso real sería algo tal que así:

```
<span wordnr="1" class="">casa</span> 
<span wordnr="2" class="">mejor</span> 
<span wordnr="3" class="">todo</span>
```

Ahora bien, sin hacer webscraping, pasando el texto en un textbox, ¿cómo podría obtener las palabras de dentro del string? (En c#)

En php, (hace mucho que no lo toco), sé que existía la funcion preg_match y que con expresiones regulares, (en el caso de curl y haciendo web scraping) con (.*) se podía sacar el valor.

Sin embargo, en c# solo se me ocurre splitear cada vez que me encuentre con:

```
<span wordnr="1" class="">
```

y

```
</span>
```

para hacer una lista con las palabras. El problema es el "1".

¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: pero ese es un xml, no se parsea como string, puedes usar librerias para obtener los valores de los nodos, lo que no mencionas es en que contexto estan esos <span>, estan quizas dentro del un <body>

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Sip, en la pagina esta dentro de un body, pero mi idea es copiarlo y pegarlo hacia un textbox (una forma cutre, no quiero tener que hacer webscraping) entonces, ¿si que sería tratado como string, no?

Comment: pero si ya tienes el string con el html no necesitas de ningun webscraping, solo usas una libreria para parsear nodos y extraer los datos, edita la pregunta y ve si pueden poner el html completo donde salen esos span que quieres parsear

Comment: Como bien dice leandro, yo no intentaría reinventar la rueda. Parsear html no es un tarea sencilla, es mejor usar librerías ya instauradas, como por ejemplo [HtlmAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso utilizar un Dom Parser sería un desperdicio de recursos, sin embargo puedes extraer las palabras de cadenas simples utilizando expresiones regulares. Por ejemplo entre los caracteres **">** y **< /**

```
// *** using System.Text.RegularExpressions; ***

string str = "<span wordnr=\"1\" class=\"\">casa</span>";
str += "<span wordnr = \"2\" class=\"\">mejor</span>";
str += "<span wordnr = \"3\" class=\"\">todo</span>";

Regex r = new Regex(@""">(.+?)\<\/"); // palabras entre "> y </
MatchCollection palabras = r.Matches(str);

foreach (Match p in palabras)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Groups[1].Value);
}

// casa
// mejor
// todo
```